# Combine kits into one batch

Tags: wine

The kit retailer supplies 2ea. 7liter bags for two kits to produce 60 bottles of wine. Can I combine the two grape juice bags into one batch to produce 30 bottles of wine? With the hopes of having better wine.

Comment: Please post a comment when you downvote, so the OP can improve his question.

Comment: This question is not very clear.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear exactly what you're asking, and I'm also not sure how combining the two kits will halve the number of bottles of wine you get?

Are you saying that the supplier provides a kit which contains two bags of juice, and you have two kits, for a total of four bags of juice? And you want to know if you can combine all 4 bags of juice into one fermenter?

If that is the question, then yes, you can.

As to whether it will make better wine, that depends on the juice. Are all the bags the same? If they are, it will not change to quality of the wine, just the number of fermenters required. If they are different juices, then your preferences will dictate whether combining the juices improves or worsens the wine.